# Using AJAX POST Value in PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to evaluate what PHP information to display depending on when a user selects that item from a list. After help and some research, I've heard a lot about AJAX and have looked into it, however, I'm a bit confused on the use of it.

I have an AJAX function to return to me a variable value from an external PHP file and it's working as anticipated. However, I would really like to capture that and set it to a PHP variable to continue my script execution. How does one accomplish this? I want to stay within the same file as the one that called the AJAX function. I don't think I fully comprehend how it all works and I'm still unsure of the exact method to get that value as a variable in my current PHP file.

My AJAX:

```
function captureName(item){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'externalFile.php',
            data: { item: item },
            success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

My PHP External File:

```
  $item = $_POST['item'];
   echo $item;
```

Stuff I want to set on my current PHP File determined by what is returned by AJAX:

```
    switch ($item){
                 case "item1":
                     $itemName = "item1";
                     $location = "location";
                     $HWType = "HW Type";
                 break;
                 case "item2":
                     $vmName = "item2";
                     $location = "location2";
                     $HWType = "HW Type2";                       
                     break; 

}
```

Comment: hmmm several items, grouped together to be processed by JavaScript. Like in an Object Notation... JavaScript Object Notation, JSON encoded with `json_encode`... see what I did there? if not: `echo json_encode(['vmName' => 'item2', 'location' => 'location2', 'HWType' => 'HW type 2']);` see what you get in the success callback

Comment: I won't attempt an answer because I am not sure I understand the question. When your `externalFile.php`  is is invoked via the POST request, whether by xhr (AJAX) or otherwise, that POSTed data is available to your script -- as you already know. You have `$_POST['item']` in hand, so you can carry on from there. So... what's the question, again?

Comment: I gathered that i have a $_POST['item'] but I want to get that information from my external php file and use that information in my current file. Is that possible? or do I have to do everything with the variable in the external file?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in 1 shot.

your javascript :

```
function captureName(item){
    console.log(item);
    $.post('externalFile.php', {item:item}, function(jsonTabInfo){
        console.log(jsonTabInfo);
    }, 'json');        
}
```

your PHP :

```
$item = $_POST['item'];

$tabInfo = array();
switch ($item){
     case "item1":
         $tabInfo['itemName'] = "item1";
         $tabInfo['location'] = "location";
         $tabInfo['HWType'] = "HW Type";
     break;
     case "item2":
         $tabInfo['vmName'] = "item2";
         $tabInfo['location'] = "location2";
         $tabInfo['HWType'] = "HW Type2";
         break; 
     default:
         $tabInfo['vmName'] = "Unknown";
         $tabInfo['location'] = "Unknown";
         $tabInfo['HWType'] = "Unknown";
}

echo json_encode($tabInfo);
```

In PHP you use JSON to send all your info to your client (javascript). Those informations are new stored in `jsonTabInfo`

Comment: I think I'm following what you're saying. I'm really new and haven't worked with JSON before. I've placed this in my code, but it only echos empty brackets. Do I need to pass anything else in?

Comment: I've modifier the `switch` with a `default`. Your problem may be due to an "item" empty or different from "item1" or "item2". Consequently, `$tabInfo` stay empty. The switch permit to know if "item" is invalid. Moreover, I've added a `console.log` of javascript variable `item` before AJAX post to check it value.

Answer (score 1):

Try using fiddler to see what data is actually getting sent via AJAX.
[Telerik Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

If it is returning empty brackets, it means no case was triggered in the switch, thus assigning to data to the $tabInfo array. Below I added a default case, with might help identify the issue.

```
switch($item) {
    case "item1":
         $tabInfo['itemName'] = "item1";
         $tabInfo['location'] = "location";
         $tabInfo['HWType']   = "HW Type";
         break;
    case "item2":
         $tabInfo['itemName'] = "item2";
         $tabInfo['location'] = "location2";
         $tabInfo['HWType']   = "HW Type 2";
         break;
    default:
         $tabInfo['itemName'] = "Undefined - " . $item;
         $tabInfo['location'] = "Undefined";
         $tabInfo['HWType']   = "Undefined";
         break;
}
```

Comment: It's returning undefined with the default case added. Thank you for your help identifying that. Does this mean there is a problem with the Javascript function?

Comment: In the default case `$tabInfo['itemName'] = "Undefined - " . $item`

It should output what "item" string is actually being passed to the Switch statement. Can you post your json return?

Comment: This is what it is returning:  {"itemName":"Undefined - ","location":"Undefined","HWType":"Undefined"}

Comment: If you notice, ItemName: Undefined - <--- Blank, nothing is being passed to the Switch statement.

Make sure the Javascript variable "Item" you are passing in your ajax call, contains something

Ex:

`data: { data: $('#myFieldSelector').val() }, `

**Remember always sanitize your user input data :)!**

Comment: Okay, I'm checking my AJAX function, ect.. Would you please explain to me where each section of code should go? I'm afraid I have something out of place. If my function is similar to what the other answer says can I just place the encoding of the JSON on my index page and not an external? Is there a need for an external at all? I'm afraid I don't understand enough about JSON and AJAX to comprehend if my stuff is in the right place.

Comment: I don't know how the information is being displayed to the user. 

If the information is static, and doesn't require interaction with a database, I would use javascript, as opposed to any ajax calls, hiding and showing content divs, or using anchor tags.

If you require the information to be delivered from a database, your present approach will work just fine.

Can you explain exactly what it is that you needed to do, because it doesn't sound like you need to use "ajax" at all.

Comment: The information will be coming from a Database. I'm trying to set a list of items and when you select that item, it will send the name of that item to a php variable and by using that name I plan on querying out information and echoing them out into a form for the user to update the database directly. It's basically a web interface for a DB. It's the determining what item they selected that I'm struggling with. I can't figure out how to use javascript to determine its name and tell PHP its value.

Comment: When I run the exact code as presented below (on the other answer) with my index.php as the $.post path. I get this error :PHP Notice:  Undefined index: item on the line with  $item = $_POST['item'];